# errors with deploy a spot in aws via template

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, templates, amazon-ec2

i am new to AWS

and when trying to deploy a spot in aws via template I got this error:

> Resource handler returned message: "Parameter:
> SpotFleetRequestConfig.IamFleetRole is invalid. (Service: Ec2, Status
> Code: 400, Request ID: f2a813c6-d43d-43bc-b6b3-69b71b1020b9)"
> (RequestToken: 35cee900-aab2-06cc-37a8-d9c9bb4fe0a2, HandlerErrorCode:
> GeneralServiceException)

that tells me nothing...
i appreciate any help to figure out what is wrong with my IamFleetRole

here is a part of my JSON template:
this is how I configure my Role:

```
            "MyRootRole": {
                "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
                "DependsOn": "ExecuteCheckCompliance",
                "Properties": {
                    "Path": "/",
                    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
                        "Statement": [{
                            "Action": [
                                "sts:AssumeRole"
                            ],
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": [{
                                    "Fn::Join": [
                                        ".",
                                        [
                                            "ec2",
                                            {
                                                "Ref": "AWS::URLSuffix"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                }]
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            "MyRolePolicies": {
                "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
                "DependsOn": "ExecuteCheckCompliance",
                "Properties": {
                    "PolicyName": "root",
                    "PolicyDocument": {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
                        "Statement": [{
                                "Action": [
                                    "s3:CreateBucket",
                                    "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                                    "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                                    "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                                    "s3:GetObject",
                                    "s3:ListBucket",
                                    "s3:GetObject",
                                    "s3:ListBucket",
                                    "s3:HeadBucket",
                                    "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                                    "s3:PutObject",
                                    "ec2:RunInstances",
                                    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                                    "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                                    "ec2:DescribeSpotInstanceRequests",
                                    "ec2:CreateTags",
                                    "ec2:RequestSpotFleet",
                                    "ec2:ModifySpotFleetRequest",
                                    "ec2:CancelSpotFleetRequests",
                                    "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                                    "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                                    "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                                    "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                                    "ec2:*"
                                ],
                                "Resource": "*",
                                "Effect": "Allow"
                            },
                            {
                                "Action": [
                                    "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                                    "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
                                    "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"
                                ],
                                "Resource": {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                                },
                                "Effect": "Allow"
                            },
                            {
                                "Action": [
                                    "ec2:CreateTags"
                                ],
                                "Resource": [{
                                        "Fn::Join": [
                                            "",
                                            [
                                                "arn:aws:ec2:",
                                                {
                                                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                                },
                                                ":",
                                                {
                                                    "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                                                },
                                                ":security-group/",
                                                {
                                                    "Ref": "MyInstanceSecurityGroup"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Fn::Join": [
                                            "",
                                            [
                                                "arn:aws:ec2:",
                                                {
                                                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                                },
                                                ":",
                                                {
                                                    "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                                                },
                                                ":instance/",
                                                {
                                                    "Ref": "MySpotInstance"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Effect": "Allow"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "Roles": [{
                        "Ref": "MyRootRole"
                    }]
                }
            }
```

and here is how i configure my SpotInstance:

```
        "MySpotInstance": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SpotFleet",
            "DependsOn": "ExecuteCheckCompliance",
            "Properties": {

                "SpotFleetRequestConfigData": {
                    "IamFleetRole": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyRootRole", "Arn"] },
                    "SpotPrice": "0.15",
                    "TargetCapacity": "0",
                    "LaunchSpecifications": [{
                        "EbsOptimized": "false",
                        "InstanceType": {
                            "Ref": "myInstanceType"
                        },
                        "ImageId": {...
                        },
                        "SecurityGroups": [{
                            "GroupId": {
                                "Ref": "MyInstanceSecurityGroup"
                            }
                        }],
                        "SubnetId": {
                            "Ref": "mySubnet"
                        },
                        "WeightedCapacity": "8",
                        "KeyName": {
                            "Ref": "keyPairName"
                        },
                        "UserData": {...}
                    }]
                }
            },

                "Metadata": {...}
        }
```

Thank's a lot for any help